# Append if not exists mysql json field

Tags: mysql, json, mysql-json

Is there a `JSON` function in mysql that will ignore trying to add the element if it already exists? For example:

```
update waitinglist SET
new = JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(new, '$', "orange")
where id=2;

update waitinglist SET
new = JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(new, '$', "orange")
where id=2;
```

Now my array looks like:

```
["apple", "orange", "orange", "orange", "orange"]
```

But I want it to work like a set, and just be:

```
["apple", "orange"]
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think so. You can test whether the value is already in the JSON in the `WHERE` clause.

```
update waitinglist SET
new = JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(new, '$', '"orange"'))
where id=2
AND NOT JSON_CONTAINS(new, '"orange"')
```

If you're updating multiple columns and need this to affect just this one column, you can use `IF()` to leave it unchanged if the value is already there.

```
update waitinglist SET
new = IF(JSON_CONTAINS(new, '"orange"'), new, JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(new, '$', '"orange"'))
where id=2
```

Comment: thanks, one question about this is when I try doing `JSON_CONTAINS(new, 'orange')` I get the following sql error: `Invalid JSON text in argument 2 to function json_contains: "Invalid value."`. Is this only available on mysql8? I'm using 5.7.

Comment: It needs to be `'"orange"'` to create a valid JSON string.